# Debian dosbox installer not working

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, raspbian

When I try to run `dosbox.installer` for Dosbox debian, I get

```
root@raspberrypi:~# ./dosbox.install
./dosbox.install: line 1: debian/dosbox.desktop: Permission denied
./dosbox.install: line 2: debian/icons/hicolor: Is a directory
./dosbox.install: line 3: usr/bin/dosbox: No such file or directory
./dosbox.install: line 4: usr/share: No such file or directory
root@raspberrypi:~#
```

How do I fix the permission denied error, and the others?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why would you do this? To install the actual **distribution provided** dosbox on RaspberryPi OS (as well as on Debian) you can simply do (as root) :

```
apt-get update
apt-get install dosbox
```

---

As for why what you attempted to install didn't work, it appears that you downloaded the source files of the RaspberryPi OS package and tried to execute a file part of the packaging process which isn't meant to be executed. This file `dosbox-0.74-3-4/debian/dosbox.install` contains:

```
debian/dosbox.desktop   usr/share/applications
debian/icons/hicolor    usr/share/icons
usr/bin/dosbox
usr/share
```

and matches OP's output (provided it was set as executable first).

The proper method to rebuild from source (because something is intended to be modified) can be found for example there: https://wiki.debian.org/BuildingTutorial

Comment: The reason I did it was because my distro of Raspbian is super old and packages no longer work. Thanks for the building link.